# Where did this IP come from on my Domain Controller?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I'm a little inexperienced with Windows Servers and am settings up a DC and DHCP role.  The local IP of the server is 192.168.0.50, it has no other network connections, so why do I see it refer to itself as 169.254.249.95 in some places?

What does this IP represent? Have I done something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP Addresses starting with 169.254 are APIPA Addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4

If you have multiple network cards, ensure that only one is used and Active.

When you set a Fixed IP Address and run ipconfig /all, if the server is still trying to get a Dynamic address, most of the cases it's due to an IP Conflict on the network.

So run an ipconfig, and check if your network configuration is properly set up.

Comment: Aha yes the box has two NICs, I disabled one and it all looks good now!  Thanks